# Lucee ORM - "Error Message" Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: orm, lucee

> Repeated column in mapping for entity: user column: userid (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

That is the error message I'm getting.  I've got a user table (customer) that is self-referential.  That way I can tell which user created which and when.

Here is my entity.

```
component  table="customer" output="false" accessors="true" persistent="true" {
  property name="userid"      column="userid"       ormtype="int"   fieldtype="id"    generator="identity";
  property name="firstname"   column="firstname"    ormtype="string";
  property name="lastname"    column="lastname"     ormtype="string";
  property name="email"       column="email"        ormtype="string";
  property name="active"      column="active"       type="boolean"  ormtype="boolean";
  property name="createdOn"   column="createdOn"    ormtype="date";
  property name="modifiedOn"  column="modifiedOn"   ormtype="date";
  property name="createdBy"   fieldtype="one-to-one"  cfc="user"    fkcolumn="userid" inverse="true";
  property name="modifiedBy"  fieldtype="one-to-one"  cfc="user"    fkcolumn="userid" inverse="true";
}
```

I've added what the error message tells me to add to each property so they now look like:

```
property name="createdBy"   fieldtype="one-to-one"  cfc="user"    fkcolumn="userid" inverse="true" insert="false" update="false";
property name="modifiedBy"  fieldtype="one-to-one"  cfc="user"    fkcolumn="userid" inverse="true" insert="false" update="false";
```

SOLUTION:
I added inversejoincolumn="userid" and it worked.  See below

```
property name="createdBy"     column="createdBy"      fieldtype="one-to-one"  cfc="user"    inversejoincolumn="userid";
property name="modifiedBy"    column="modifiedBy"     fieldtype="one-to-one"  cfc="user"    inversejoincolumn="userid";
```

Comment: So is the error still there after making your changes and calling `OrmReload()`?

Comment: I need to be able to save/update those columns (createdBy and modifiedBy), but yes, if I add that code to ALL of the userid columns, including the primary key, it works, but since I need to save the data, it doesn't technically 'work'.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add it to the identiy `userid` property.  But anyway it seems you need to create specific keys for your 2 self-referential relationships.

Comment: This is what fixed it

    property name="modifiedBy"    column="modifiedBy"     fieldtype="one-to-one"  cfc="user"    inversejoincolumn="userid";

I added inversejoinclumn to both modifiedBy and createdBy.  thank you to everyone for there suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In your customers table create separate columns to record the IDs of the users who do the creating and modifying. You could call them `creatorid` and `modifierid`.

Then change the `fkcolumn` in your `createdBy` and `modifiedBy` relationships from `userid` to `creatorid` and `modifierid` respectively.